# How to post a tweet using django and python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, api, twitter, python-social-auth

I'm new using django and APIs, so I hope you can help me.

I'm using python-social-auth to get access to user's twitter, but right now I just finished this tutorial [tutorial for oauth](https://realpython.com/blog/python/adding-social-authentication-to-django/)

I would like to know what should I do to be able to post a tweet.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With python-social-auth you will only get some info about the user, if he accepts. But you won't be able to tweet using his account.

Comment: I though I can obtain his access token and therefore using to post a tweet. Where can I find a code or a library to use oauth in twitter to post with the account? Thank you for you answer.